# Either monad in TypeScript + pattern matching

Tags: typescript, monads, typescript-generics, either

I'm trying to implement Either monad in TypeScript.

```
interface Either<TResult, TError> {

  flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, TError>): Either<R, TError>;

  match<R>(result: (success: TResult) => R, error: (err: TError) => R): R;
}

class Left<TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly error: TError) {}

  public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, TError>): Either<R, TError> {

    return new Left(this.error);
  }

  public match<R>(success: (value: TResult) => R, error: (err: TError) => R): R {
    return error(this.error);
  }
}

class Right<TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly value: TResult) {}

  public flatMap<R>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, TError>): Either<R, TError> {

    return f(this.value);
  }

  public match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: (err: TError) => R): R {
    return success(this.value);
  }
}

class ResourceError {
}

class ObjectNotFound  {

  public constructor(public readonly msg: string, public readonly code: number) {
  }
}

function f1(s: string): Either<number, ObjectNotFound> {
  return new Right(+s);
}

function f2(n: number): Either<number, ResourceError> {
  return new Right(n + 1);
}

function f3(n: string): Either<string, ObjectNotFound> {
  return new Right(n.toString());
}

const c = f1('345') 
// (*) line 58 - error: Type 'Either<number, ResourceError>' is not assignable to type 'Either<number, ObjectNotFound>'. 
  .flatMap(n => f2(n)) 
  .flatMap(n => f3(n));

const r = c.match(
  (result: string) => result,
  (err: ObjectNotFound) => err.msg
);
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=64&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLDAC2gHgCoBKEAzgK4A2YANMnqlFAPZQB8yA3gLABQPyyMcnDABZOAAccBFgAoYALmQyAbnHKkIiwiQpgAlMgC8bdFlwEadBsxZ7Fp7FCmX6TVgG4efZAFthCTClZKB1KRRkyBCRiYi0iMkoDY2QLZGg3cPStV2YktgI7FM9uAF8vbgQhGOQAGQgYMHx43RdrVmRgH3FyCB8IcGI0DEcm0OpaHPauXm5+cVIAI3JgBGQERhBiMChSBDBmGXEoYFVIZBC4ABMN8gBPNLbstoN2Mpm5xeXVwWExSWk5OFVOpNLRmokjCZhuZWm5bPZoU5UlY4Rxyvx+CEwKQoCBkCAIAB3Wr1MAyLDAYgAOnSuWK-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-mA5wFQgVLdgEMjeEOYzeXRhbDi0E3TmxYURVxn5CukI1QTwrZAA).

As different functions can potentially generate errors of different types, flatMap chaining breaks.

I assume, overall intention is clear from the code. And I hope I've chosen the right tool (either monad).

Can anyone suggest a fix to make it all work?

**[UPDATE]:** Thanks to [SpencerPark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10609635/spencerpark) for the nudge in right direction.
The full implementation with .match working as originally intended is below (inspired by [this](https://medium.com/@fillopeter/pattern-matching-with-typescript-done-right-94049ddd671c) post):

```
type UnionOfNames<TUnion> = TUnion extends { type: any } ? TUnion["type"] : never

type UnionToMap<TUnion> = {
  [NAME in UnionOfNames<TUnion>]: TUnion extends { type: NAME } ? TUnion : never
}

type Pattern<TResult, TMap> = {
  [NAME in keyof TMap]: (value: TMap[NAME]) => TResult;
}

type Matcher<TUnion, TResult> = Pattern<TResult, UnionToMap<TUnion>>;


interface Either<TResult, TError> {

  flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;

  match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R;
}

class Left<TResult, TError extends { type: any }> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly error: TError) {}

  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError> {
    return new Left(this.error);
  }

  public match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R {
    return (error as any)[this.error.type](this.error);
  }
}

class Right<TResult, TError> implements Either<TResult, TError> {

  public constructor(private readonly value: TResult) {}

  public flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError> {
    return f(this.value);
  }

  match<R>(success: (result: TResult) => R, error: Matcher<TError, R>): R {
    return success(this.value);
  }
}

class ResourceError {
  type = "ResourceError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly resourceId: number) {}
}

class ObjectNotFound {
  type = "ObjectNotFound" as const

  public constructor(public readonly msg: string, public readonly timestamp: string) {}
}

class DivisionByZero {
  type = "DivisionByZero" as const
}

class NetworkError {
  type = "NetworkError" as const

  public constructor(public readonly address: string) {}
}


function f1(s: string): Either<number, DivisionByZero> {
  return new Right(+s);
}

function f2(n: number): Either<number, ResourceError> {
  return new Right(n + 1);
}

function f3(n: number): Either<string, ObjectNotFound> {
  return new Right(n.toString());
}

function f4(s: string): Either<number, NetworkError> {
  return new Left(new NetworkError('someAdress'));
}

const c = f1('345')
  .flatMap(n => f2(n))
  .flatMap(n => f3(n))
  .flatMap(s => f4(s));

const r = c.match(
  (result: number) => result.toString(),
  {
    ObjectNotFound: (value: ObjectNotFound) => 'objectNotFound',
    ResourceError: (value: ResourceError) => 'resourceError',
    DivisionByZero: (value: DivisionByZero) => 'divisionByZero',
    NetworkError: (value: NetworkError) => value.address
  }
);

console.log(r);
```

Updated playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=101&pc=16#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwPIDMByBDAthAZwB4AVeZOAPigF4ozEUoIAPYCOAEwKgG8pQkAFxRscEFAC+UAPz1yKANoAiQRGUBdKCLgQAbhABOAWABQZtbEZwSSALLYwpBVVp8zUKIswBBOwFEoBDgrCgwcfGIGCkoNEWimVnYuHn41EV8AqVl5a20oXQMTU0kzC3BoAAVsYHZDOFIAJUIAVwAbYAAaegcwajpeDy9MwOCoAGsIECR0Hsc4qAAKPWw2loh43u8-fw0ASlpqEmaCduAAbjNS81NLB2AAYwALI2drbuPWjv6oatqjBqfU4dbouWy9N4xSiXG5mYJ1dDYB7QfwIYAvQxNL5dej+QyGJCGaiDG6edBtGoQxrdfyURboETLVbreInM4HGjUVHo17UqC0vYibkYoh8wIAH1x+MJ0LKpk8uBqz1FdNOD2RBAIjMM2NZ2I51D5RgJhhE92erxIeJN3UalEFUEaMOuZgeFM1UAAMhB0MAscCcVbpYZmGwONw+AIKiIxBJJNQELgwG0IPg4MAeMLLWyQVKTcS5Z4wC0AEZtBAPKAPFAEYCGFoPYCExZgQwIFbsKA67CcFBtCTGwnxa2Eg68F3yqDFssVqDkymOUU0ukMpYrNYbeg54AG-lokVi+1C-e8mlQSVB-PuSeeHXAFr1AoQADuXp9wEW6IQBAAdIPDHsMKeBORaluWlaKo8TwqosaoalqSw6gGeoBruRrBmaSoipehK2kejrXp4t4QPej6LP+og8LGeyKF+v7-j+agaJ+Tzfn+waAUM1wTm62Aeo0CAAOZPH6QJnB8I5EkESYpmmGZ7jymJibmOFSSSQzTuBVY1nWDZNoYLZth20Ddr2cD9lA64slu+p8CBU5gbO87AFSy70oyVmbspO6HApB7Lg6WaYmK555jKhFEXeD4hOgLFsZ5nGTvZkHKnasENvB2q6jZqG+ehJqYVBlqSXhDqNBFxGkSEcGEAQcW-glQFSFccq8fxhBIA+yKSRFlh0MoJydYY3XBsolHaXAtaFg5M6VtWk26Y2zaabOpl9hISFDciACSnA6C0uAlkYY7ca17o8KgJYAFYQI2mBIMAABinVcL1FRuMol03XdD3PS0XBjXxE1TaSM1afNtb1ktBkrZWa3mRIuAEIJIiQ8EgndLDXYQD260CImhDAHgYCo3W6MnS1NxtTwAAi7bfhQABCIAAFpGEgb2QB9dN6AzKDM2zBKAzwEPAJTrrnVAmAkc+hLjD1JKeH1UDKNLwCy4Y8ujeNovTVjotQ-pLaOXDONmRZPacEhCFo3AgkUyUcpmOg-2NhQc4AIywaTbZ24FJ6YnAB1HYY3Q83zcAC+zBaTlFj66K+AnCR+ADUBCJROLtwG7TDoAATIscD7Ydx3HopRBByXoeOh1XUQJJMeVdFT6J0JImF1AKdQB7GdylnOcxQAzIXxch-75e2xjUBfbdwD3U9L2cI32NVS3jptx+cCMUgADKZN24sey9zc-fAO76AACze1Ak-jyKlch90asa1rV6KyvzcJ2+vqFy+Usy3LSSiwADkBAkD4B8FbWqwCj7OlajpKsbh0Be2AYPC+ABWGBQwfzOV6B3Tkc4C5wCPtg3Bjh8HUHQMPYhexSEUhcuQngBDL6wVgfAhaXY3APB-ClJ4iwhiLCQmcUex1fJCI6NvPevtBKH06EMd+ngZ4-QXv9Paa5mSbiUXPX6i9dzAKQNdWe88-pcGAXIm8NcwF10kh5DRIhBrWI4r5YBm1HEmjMUMTw4cCBM1ZuzWxG4RDeN8YLJAejOD0x8fzPxBIPEWOfoAjC6jAn-3Vokk0u5PI-kttbLiZhEquhrEgFMP42hIBkQBc4QA).

**[UDPDATE 2]:**
'catchall' clause support:

```
type DiscriminatedUnion<T> = { type: T }

type UnionOfNames<TUnion> = TUnion extends DiscriminatedUnion<string> ? TUnion["type"] : never

type UnionToMap<TUnion> = {
  [NAME in UnionOfNames<TUnion>]: TUnion extends DiscriminatedUnion<NAME> ? TUnion : never
}

type Pattern<TResult, TMap> = {
  [NAME in keyof TMap]: (value: TMap[NAME]) => TResult
} | ({
  [NAME in keyof TMap]?: (value: TMap[NAME]) => TResult
} & { catchall: (value: DiscriminatedUnion<string>) => TResult})

// ... SKIPPED ...

const r1 = c.match(
  (result: string) => result,
  {
    // when there is the 'catchall' case, others are optional. But still only the possible cases can be listed.
    ObjectNotFound: (value: ObjectNotFound) => value.msg + value.timestamp,
    catchall: (value: DiscriminatedElement<string>) => 'catchall ' + value.type
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the signature of `flatMap` to the following:

```js
flatMap<R, E>(f: (value: TResult) => Either<R, E>): Either<R, E | TError>;
```

Here the error type is either the error from the previous computation or the one returned by the current one. Conceptually that follows from what `Either` models. The type at the end of the chain in your example is `Either<string, ObjectNotFound | ResourceError>` as expected. (After fixing what looks like a typo, `f3(n: number)...`).

The overall computation could return an `ObjectNotFound` error or `ResourceError` depending on what step failed.

The final match now properly raises a type error because the `error` function doesn't handle the case where a `ResourceError` is raised as possible from `f2`.

See the [updated playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=62&ssc=3&pln=59&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLDAC2gHgCoBKEAzgK4A2YANMnqlFAPZQB8yA3gLABQPyyMcnDABZOAAccBGqhYAKGAC5kcgG5xypCMsIkKYAJTIAvG3RZc0tCwPLz2KFJnIAPrXpNWAbh59kAW2EETCl5KD1KZTkyBCRiYh0iMkojU2QraE8ozJ0PZlS2Alt0n24AX19uBCF45AAZCBgwfCT9GjoGZjZgf3FyCH8IcGI0DAcWiOp3TtYOSv5xUgAjcmAEZARGEGIwKFIEMGY5cShgdUhkcLgAEy3yAE9kTOZcmaN2Ct5uBeXV9cFhGJJFZZAooupNNpaK0UiYzGNLDIbHYEY4Qa5pp42FxvvxLhAwKQoCBkCAIAB3eqNMByLDAYgAOmeUAMpX4nz8ixWawCQRCBHkMTiCRUEK0iUmBXSNGZ2QYr08UqKygIc1x-HChOJTxmtMw9KZbzZyE+HKqNRGBGAAHNMM1dMkph0scgen0BkMwCN7LgHW1MV01ZzfjzNttdvtDlBjqdzigrrcQA9kGKoX7YR95sguX8BEJRBInNYwaKNOLoZK4aMLGikcUfbW0BjnYGcXj8VqSTA9QbU6y-Gaftz1oEwMFQtF9sKouFHRLHUqZTM5VAFfkq8r0mr25qiSShSRiD3GX3jabKtU4LUkowiUg8lA1WbL7UAPJLABWEAOADlGGAADFbxAa5+BxYNhw2LYdj2A4jhzHkEzuR5-GIa1lBg0BrRoBD1iQpNHk2a4oRAUh-CWaB3gHHgzRgUgQAOYAtgEABGaIMN2LD61RHBSPI6AaHfL9f3-ID6OubE-F3bUyUpK1bRpABqYh+3KSo6IYsAmK7AAmOQQGUPiKJZFEa14sjjJoG87wgB9JNxaSSVk9IbTtfTkEU5AWNU2j6MY5iYAAZn0wyLMo0zxkwkBsOQITvzAP9AOAiTtw7PdSQpFyFP0hlDgAZU46K5AMHyL2gsANhMVi5AAckCgAWABWGqDD8BkAQLcR3LSGA9JAEq2o6oFurYIL9JK0oeDDHZLiqhAGVHYI5D8ORZ30DjTmiqU1soKgVpyWLP3ixKxJAqVMgWtCeFZIA)

Comment: I'm now a bit puzzled why c.match() has type: 
Either<string, ObjectNotFound | ResourceError>.match<ObjectNotFound | ResourceError>(result: (success: string) => ObjectNotFound | ResourceError, error: (err: ObjectNotFound | ResourceError) => ObjectNotFound | ResourceError): ObjectNotFound | ResourceError

instead of R ('string').. The type inference logic here eludes me.. Anybody?